# GWT and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, gwt

Do you think that using just GWT and Hibernate sound like a "sane" solution for a web application that needs a very rich UI?

Comment: do a search for hibernate+gwt and you'll find out that the answer is 'yes'

Comment: thank you for you answer. i have done that. scaling is my concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, Yes.

You seem to have 2 requirements:

**Rich user interface:**
As you probably know, GWT can be used to make Rich UI applications. The possibilities is virtually endless.
Hibernate does not play any role in point 1.

**Scalability,**
There is indeed a great overhead with the datamodels since every Hibernate entity will have to be mapped with a GWT model when sending them to the client. As users have specified above, there are third party applications that help you do so. Adding new data models will trigger changes to both server and client code. However if your architecture is strong enought, this should not be a big issue.

Answer (score 3):

GWT and Hibernate are NOT a natural match. For complete information about why and how you can work with both of them together, read http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/webtoolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html.

But to sum it up, you will have 3 options:

- Use plain Data Transfer Objects (DTOs).
- Use Dozer. With Dozer, you are still using DTOs, but Dozer will do most of the work for you.
- Use Gilead for "magical" transformation between your GWT side and the server side.

In my experience, "magical" solutions are wonderful when they work. When they don't, well, good luck. So if I were in your shoes, I would pick either option 1 or 2.

Comment: Gilead is no more maintained and nothing guarantees it works with Hibernate 3.5+ (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/toulouse-jug/pL1bNG3-gc0/rolqY-p-qGsJ)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it is used a lot. Basically you have a two options:

- use DTOs and always initialize your hibernate entities on the server
- use [gilead](http://noon.gilead.free.fr/gilead/)

Answer (score 1):

I think a nicer solution that has been solved in GWT 2.1+ is by making use of RequestFactory and the Entity/ValueProxy mechanism. For more detailed understanding of this idiom in GWT refer to this http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/trunk/DevGuideRequestFactory.html

Comment: Thank you! Looks like Google are filling the gaps themselves, which makes things easier since one does not have to rely upon magic from third parties, like rreyes1979 suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Is a really good architecture, but you will need this for a perfect match.

http://beanlib.sourceforge.net/

```
  //To response RPC with just the current entity
  return new Hibernate3DtoCopier().hibernate2dto(entity); 

  //To response RPC with the entity with their related entities. 
  return new Hibernate3DtoCopier().hibernate2dtoFully(entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Gilead missleads the most when thinking about GWT applications. When designing a GWT application as 3 tier architecture, the first you will think about is that the web tier is the gwt generated JavaScript UI and the application tier is your RPC service, but this is not the case. Both of them belongs to the web tier. When thinking about the web tier you would normally make a data tranformation to the data that has to be displayed. But this will not happend when using Gilead and you have no to chance to do this. So I would always recommend to use a data mapper like Dozer, also when you transfer currently all the data from the database to the UI. When your application grows the time will come where you need transformation!

Answer (score 0):

Surely it is.

I make a tutorial to help people to know how to integrate the libs. Check it:

http://singularityprogramming.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/gwt-2-4-0-hibernate-3-6-10-final/